# Interface building - UIViews vs Images vs Core graphics vs PDF subclass

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, interface-builder, core-graphics

My app uses flat graphics, which mostly consists of lines and flat surfaces...

**Whats the best approach for building the UI?**

- use PNG images as much as possible (like for the attached picture, the whole background would be an image)
- use 4 UIViews (in this example case) with background color to make the background and the 3 lines
- use CoreGraphics to actually draw in drawRect (or somewhere else?)?
- subclass UIView and draw PDF content
- any other approach?

What are the performance impacts? The advantage of the first two, is that they can be done in IB, but is there a downside (like performance or quality or caching)? I also heard of a trend of using CoreGraphics for drawing all the time...

[image: sample of graphics]

Comment: @ThilinaHewagama That's not that simple.

Comment: @Peter Lapisu, yes it's easy to use PNG files. 1 for background and better to put other images inside UIImageViews (on top of background view);

Comment: One big View. Two small views on top of that. 3 images top, bottom and vertical.

Answer (score 0):

As H2CO3 said is not that simple. Each format suits particular requirements, there are no written laws, I just ca tell you what I do.

1. Small pieces of UI, such as buttons, icons etc: I normally use PNG or PDF. You can subclass a UIView to draw PDF vector content. The plus with PDF is that if the source is a vector image, you could not take care about physical-logical points.
2. Images or Hi-res images, such as image of a content: In this case I use JPG, for they small size respect of PNG. They take little bit more to decompress but usually the size is very smaller compared to PNG.
3. In general PNG can use alpha, JPG no

Image is a big topic, nowadays I always try a way to find symmetry in UI elements and use stretchable UIImages with PNG.
For you example I will use PNG witch stretchable left and right side. Instead of use 640 px image, you can use 10 px image, with stretchable right margin and stretchable left margin.
**[update]**
It should be said that if you use stretchable images you will get a lot of performance boost, since the image will be smaller, you will occupy less memory on the "disk", less memory on the heap thatnks to the GPU stretching and less decompressing times
.

Comment: how can you subclass UIView to draw PDF? can you give an example in your answer?

Comment: Ovveriding -drawRect and using Core Graphics check this ;-) http://mattgemmell.com/2012/02/10/using-pdf-images-in-ios-apps/

Answer (score 0):

So basically the fastest way is to use PNG files (stretchable and normal), also if you are using  PNG files it will be easy to change the design and fix eventual bugs.

When you are using PNG files, try to reduce the size of the PNGs (stretchable images for backgrounds) for a better performance and a small size of the app.

CoreGraphics is more complex and can add strange bugs or performance problems if you don't know what you are doing, but can be use also for simple view styling.

On every project that I've done I couldn't use only one of these two because of the project complexity or because I was to lazy to open photoshop and add extract some designs.